# redirect a subdomain to a remote url, preferably via only DNS setting or with httpd.conf, without changing url displayed

Tags: apache, dns

For example I wish to redirect list.mydomain.com to http://my.emailingapp.com/lists/

but keeping the name displayed in URL as "list.mydomain.com".

Note that all parameters are to be passed over. e.g. list.mydomain.com/?stuff=a should be the same with http://my.emailingapp.com/lists/?stuff=a

Another note: these domains are on different server.

There are many other similar posts, but all of them does not work exactly as I wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a `CNAME` record for list.mydomain.com to my.emailingapp.com using which you can achieve the following.

- URL remains list.mydomain.com
- The arguments get displayed in URL as list.mydomain.com/?stuff=a

Your requirement of having `/lists/` should be implementable by URL rewrite rules.